# Set window to full screen with python?

Tags: python, windows, screen, ctypes, fullscreen

How do I set a window of my choice into full screen mode with python (on Windows)?
I remember seeing something like that somewhere using ctypes.

I do know that you can set a window to be focussed, so it does not seem too far off for me.